# 404 error when I try to update my form with id 1, but its not happen to another id

Tags: php, codeigniter, web

[image: i have db with id 1,2,4]

[image: but if I try to update id_bank = 1, i got 404 error]

[image: but that update work with another id]

i have db with id 1,2,4 (img-1)
but if I try to update id_bank = 1, i got 404 error (img-2)
but that update work with another id (img-3)
this application work fine yesterday, but I got this error this morning, I dont know why, I really need help :(

Update:
I use codeigniter framework,
this is my controller code

```
  function form($id_bank = false)
    {
    $this->id_bank  = $id_bank;
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="error">', '</div>');
        $data['page_title']     = lang('bank_form');
        $data['breadcrumbs'] = array();
        $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
            'text' => lang('home'),
            'href' => base_url()
            );
        $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
            'text' => lang('bank_form'),
            'href' => base_url('bank')
            );
        //default values are empty if the provinsi is new
        $data['id_bank']       = '';
        $data['nama_bank']      = '';               
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('nama_bank', 'lang:nama_bank', 'trim|required|max_length[64]');
        //$this->form_validation->set_rules('id_categories', 'lang:id_categories', 'trim|required|max_length[64]');
        // validate the form
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            $this->view('bank/form', $data);
        }
        else
        {
            if (!$this->auth->hasPermission('modify', 'bank')) 
            {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('error', lang('error_acces'));
                redirect('bank');
            }

            $this->load->helper('text');

            $save['id_bank']        = $id_bank;
            $save['nama_bank']          = $this->input->post('nama_bank');

            $this->Model_bank->save_provinsi($save);

            $this->session->set_flashdata('message', lang('message_provinsi_saved'));
            //go back to the category list
            redirect('bank');
        }
}
```

this is on my view

```
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th><?php echo lang('no');?></th>
                    <th><?php echo sort_url('nama_bank', 'nama_bank', $order_by, $sort_order, $code);?></th>
                    <th><?php echo sort_url('gambar', 'image', $order_by, $sort_order, $code);?></th>
                    <th class="text-center"><?php echo lang('action');?></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

                <?php echo (count($type) < 1)?'<tr><td style="text-align:center;" colspan="5">'.lang('no_type').'</td></tr>':''?>

                <?php
                $pages = ($page-1)*10;
                foreach ($type as $merks):
                    $pages+=1;

                ?>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width:10px;"><?php echo  $pages; ?></td>
                    <td style=""><?php echo  $merks->nama_bank; ?></td>
                    <td style="text-align:center"> <span><img  width="50px" height="50px" src='<?php echo $this->config->item('url_image').'photo/bank/'.$merks->image?>'></span></td>
                    <td style="width:10%;" class="text-center">
                        <a href="<?php echo site_url('bank/form/'.$merks->id_bank); ?>" data-toggle="tooltip" title=" <?php echo lang('edit');?>" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
                        <?php if ($this->auth->hasPermission('delete', 'bank')) {  ?>
                        <a href="<?php echo site_url('bank/delete/'.$merks->id_bank); ?>" data-toggle="tooltip" onclick="return areyousure();" title="<?php echo lang('delete');?>" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            <?php endforeach;?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

this on my routes:

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

 $route['default_controller']   = "dashboard";
```

Comment: You have not provided near enough information for anyone to help you. Post the associated code? Tell us what you've changed?

Comment: A look at the Route information woudl also be useful

Comment: Try in config/routes.php `$route['bank/form/(:num)'] = 'bank/form/$1';`

Comment: Examples here https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html#examples

Comment: still not work sir, I think I need to say that I never touch that routes.php before

Comment: Please put the model code.

Comment: this also happen even if i not load the model.

Comment: i found new issue, 404 appeared if I access data with id 1, 11 , 111 , etc. , I added data with id 11 and 111 to my database and when I try to access it, 404 appeared.
But, this not happen with another id (2,3,4,5,6 etc)